# What are the steps to perform Maha mrityunjaya mantra japa?

Tags: shiva, mantras, japa

What are the exact steps to be followed to perform Maha Mrityunjaya mantra Japa?

How many times per day the japa should be performed? For how many days it should be done?

Also kindly elaborate on yama and niyama to be followed for this mantra japa.